# How do I invert this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given two vectors $$\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
    v_1\\
    \vdots\\
    v_n
  \end{pmatrix} ,
\vec{w} = \begin{pmatrix}
    w_1\\
    \vdots\\
    w_n
  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

such that for all $1 \leq j, k \leq n$

- $v_j \neq v_k $ for $j \neq k$
- $w_j \neq w_k $ for $j \neq k$
- $v_j \neq w_k $
- $v_j >0 \quad $
- $w_j >0 \quad $

Define a Matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$ with entries $a_{jk}$, for $1 \leq j, k \leq n$, by

$$a_{j k} :=\frac{1}{(v_j - w_k)^2}$$

Is there any simple way to get an expression for its inverse?
I'm really a newbie in linear algebra, this object seems simple enough to be already known, but I can't solve this nor find it solved anywhere.
Thanks in advance! :)